# get specific object from dynamodb with given value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I have dynamodb table with item as :

```
{
   primaryKey: 1,
   "obj1": {
      status: allow,
      "a":1
   },
   "obj2": {
      status: allow,
      "a":1
   },
   "obj3": {
      status: deny,
      "a":2
   }
}
```

I need to query dynamo such that it should return only objects with given a value. For ex.: if i provide value of primary key: 1 and a: 1 then it should return :

```
"obj1": {
     status: allow,
     "a":1
  }
  "obj2": {
     status: allow,
     "a":1
  }
```

Can someone please help me to query dynamo. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the query result using [filter expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.FilterExpression)

Also, you might want to understand how it works and specifically that it will not reduce your resource usage.

> A filter expression is applied after a Query finishes, but before the results are returned. Therefore, a Query will consume the same amount of read capacity, regardless of whether a filter expression is present.

Comment: Could you please try to give us the query here as I tried using the filter expression already but not able to achieve the output?

Comment: I misread the schema. You need to split this 1 record into multiple records by using a secondary index on "a". Post that you can either filter it or use a query with condition on "a".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure how you are storing your data currently, but this can be done. 
Have your partition key as the primary key and have objectID as your sort key. Now if you query by primary-key, & choose all items in that partition, you'll get all the objectIDs present in that primary key.

Now for your query which you want to check the attribute "a" for each object you can do it two ways:

1. Add a filter which will do a read on all your objects and after that it will use the filter to filter out any objects without the condition you have specified.
2. Add a global secondary index. This will essentially make it so that you don't have to read all the objects in a particular primarykey. You can specify a GSI with the partition key as primarykey and sort key as the attribute "a". To query for all the objects in a particular primary-key with a = 1, you'll just need to query with primary-key=1 & attribute-a=1. This approach is especially good if you have 100s-1000s of objects present but only a few of them have attribute-a=1. Instead of reading all the 100s-1000s of attributes, we'll only read the ones with the desired value.